Simplification for finding critical numbers
The question is how to find the critical numbers of
y=(x-2)(x+2)^1/3.
I recall in class that there's a simplification that makes the derivative much simpler but I don't see any type of simplification.

I know the product rule for derivatives.  When I use the product rule for derivatives I get a denominator that is not easy to set = 0

Are we looking at $\sqrt[3]{(x-2)(x+2)}$ or $(x-2)\sqrt[3]{x+2}$? Show your full attempt, so we can see where we can help.

The latter.  I used the product derivative rule.  I want to find x so that the numerator is zero .  My numerator is:  x-2+(x+2)^(1/3)

Just take the derivative using the product rule and power rule, using negative exponents when needed (rather than writing in fraction form). Then factor out $(x+2)^{-\frac{2}{3}},$ the least power of $x+2,$ and it will be easy to solve for where the numerator is zero and where the denominator is zero. This is a standard method for products of polynomials to various powers, by the way, as the fact that the degrees after differentiation are $1$ less than before makes what shows up "inside the factoring parentheses" easy to work with.

ah, beautiful.  I see this now.  Light bulb on.  Thank you

As an example of "easy to work with", try it for $;(x^2 - 3x + 2)^{\frac{6}{5}}(5x - 8)^{\frac{2}{3}}.;$ You'll find that all the hard-to-work-with fractional exponentiated terms clump together as a product (easy to set equal to zero) times a relatively simple polynomial (easy to set equal to zero).
